# How to check input for content in multiple lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I kind of noob question probably, but how do I check if the input of "Answer" is in multiple lists? I want to be able to identify if the input is a part of both "Vokalar" and "Konsonantar". For future I would also like to be able to identify how many times the input is a part of each list.

```
Vokalar= ("a","e","i","o","u","y","æ","ø","å")
Konsonantar=("b","c","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","m","n","p","q","r","s","t","v","w","x","z")

Loop = 1

while Loop == 1:
    Answer = input("Word-check ;)")
    
    if Answer in Vokalar and Konsonantar:
        print("word")
    else:
        print("not word")
```

Comment: if (Answer in Vokalar) and (Answer in Konsonantar):, paranthesis are not necessary added it only for readability, if you want to check if it is in at-least 1 list you can use 'or' instead of 'and'.

Comment: Are you expecting a word at `Answer = input("Word-check ;)")`?

Answer (score 0):

```
if Answer in Vokalar and Answer in Konsonantar:
```

But if you will have more lists later on, you could define a variable withh all of your check lists and check it this way:

```
check_lists = [Vokalar, Konsonantar, <other lists>]
if all(Answer in list_ for list_ in check_lists):
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to check every char in the answer string and compare it with the list not all the string

```
Vokalar= ("a","e","i","o","u","y","æ","ø","å")
Konsonantar= ("b","c","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","m","n","p","q","r","s","t","v","w","x","z")

Loop = 1

while Loop == 1:

Answer = input("Word-check : ")
isWord = True
for i in  Answer:
    if i in Vokalar or i in Konsonantar:
        pass
    else:
        isWord = False
if isWord :
    print("word")
else :
    print("not word")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# function to count number of occurences
def countOccurences(itemToCheck, itemsList):
    count = 0
    for item in itemsList:
        if item == itemToCheck:
            count += 1
    return count


Vokalar = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y", "æ", "ø", "å")
Konsonantar = ("b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m",
               "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "z")

Loop = 1

while Loop:
    Answer = input("Word-check ;)")

    if Answer in Vokalar and Answer in Konsonantar:
        vokalarOccurences = countOccurences(Answer, Vokalar)
        konsonantarOccurences = countOccurences(Answer, Konsonantar)
        print(f"{Answer} is found in both lists. Vokalar: {vokalarOccurences} times and Konsonantar: {konsonantarOccurences} times")

    elif Answer in Vokalar:
        vokalarOccurences = countOccurences(Answer, Vokalar)
        print(f"{Answer} is found in Vokalar list. Vokalar: {vokalarOccurences} times")

    elif Answer in Konsonantar:
        konsonantarOccurences = countOccurences(Answer, Konsonantar)
        print(f"{Answer} is found in Konsonantar list. Konsonantar: {konsonantarOccurences} times")

    else:
        print(f"{Answer} not found in any list.")
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if an answer is a word you can just use the builtin method of the string `isalpha`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha

If you want to do it manually is better to use `sets`:

```py
def check_answer(answer: str) -> bool:
    cur_set = set(answer)
    vok = set(Vokalar) & cur_set
    kon = set(Konsonantar) & cur_set
    return len(cur_set) == len(vok) + len(kon) # len must be equal to sum of vok and kon to be a correct word
```

To count the occurrence there is an builtin collection (a special dictionary):
https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

```py
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(answer)
print(c.keys())
print(c.get('a', 0))  # to get the count for a char
```

Then, you can check for each count in which list it is and print the counter:

```py
for elm, count in c.items():
    if elm in Vokalar:
        print(elm, "in Vokalar", count, "times")
    elif elm in Konsonantar:
        print(elm, "in Konsonantar", count, "times")
```

> Please note that you don't manage the upper and lower cases with those lists but the `isalpha` method does it...

Answer (score -1):

To count occurencies of answer in both list you can use code:

```
cnt_vokalar = Vokalar.count(Answer)
cnt_konsonantar = Konsonantar.count(Answer)
```

Then you could check if number of occurencies is greater than 0:

```
while Loop == 1:
    Answer = input("Word-check ;)")
    cnt_vokalar = Vokalar.count(Answer)
    cnt_konsonantar = Konsonantar.count(Answer)
    if cnt_vokalar > 0 and cnt_konsonantar > 0:
        print("word")
    else:
        print("not word")
```